# I want to make the background an image with react, but a white part is created

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I want to set the background screen with react, but I can only set the background screen for the file upload part.

## What you want to ask

How should I set the background screen to the entire surface and adjust the background screen according to the size of the web page?

## Code

```
import React from "react";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import FileUpload from "./compornents/FileUpload";

function App () {
   return (
       <div className = "App">
         <FileUpload />
       </ div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'entire surface' means here? Is the background image to fill the viewport or is it to fill the whole page? And is it actually to fill (without losing aspect-ratio) or is it to be seen in its entirety regardless of viewport/page aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file and name it style.css and reference the App div

```
.App {
    background-image: url("./assets/pic.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

then import it to your app.js

```
import "./style.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the image as a URL then you can use background-size cover to fit into your div

```js
{
  background-image: url("Yout Image URL");
  background-size: cover;
}
```